# Boot Rpi 0W via start-signal from Arduino Nano 33 IOT

Tags: pi-zero, arduino, raspberry-pi-os

My Arduino Nano 33 IOT and Rpi 0W can either share or have their own 5V powerbanks. I would like to boot Rpi via a signal from my Arduino, i.e. the Rpi boots on Arduinos command. Can this be done? How? They will be connected via an USB cable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do some soldering, you should be able to add a sort of "power button" functionality by connecting a transistor controlled by the Arduino instead of a button.

Here is an article saying how to add a power button but switch out the button for a transistor and it should work I believe: https://howchoo.com/g/mwnlytk3zmm/how-to-add-a-power-button-to-your-raspberry-pi#understanding-the-wake-functionality

Comment: I got the rpi up running by connecting pins 5 and 6. Thanks! And the shutdown process should be done using e.g. sudo shutdown now. How to do the thing with the transistor? I don't have any experience in this area

Comment: A small transistor like the PN2222? https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-arduino-lesson-13-dc-motors/transistors

Comment: I don't have much experience with transistors either. I'd recommend looking at this tutorial for using them https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HqhE-8xXeCQ . I'd assume it'd work but make sure that you're still getting the correct voltage through it.

Comment: All the Simply Electronics videos are pretty good for learning electronics btw.